# Cannot receive data on STM32F746 UDP socket via LwIP

Tags: sockets, udp, stm32, lwip, stm32f7

I've been trying to get the LwIP stack to work on my STM32F746 Discovery board, but no luck so far when it comes to receiving data. Sending works just fine, but for some reason, I can't receive any packets. Wireshark confirms that the packets are sent, but the board seems to ignore them. My assumption is that some configuration in stm32f7xx_hal_conf.h has been done incorrectly, but I have very limited experience when it comes to this, so I haven't been able to figure it out.

Here's how I initialize my socket:

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
struct sockaddr_in address;
int addrlen = sizeof(address);

address.sin_len = addrlen;
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
address.sin_port = htons(port);

bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&address, addrlen);
printf("Listening on socket %d\n", sock);
printf("Received %d bytes\n", recv(sock, buffer, 200, 0));
```

The second to last line gets printed, then the thread blocks indefinitely waiting for a packet. As I said, if I'm sending data instead of receiving it, everything works fine. I also tried the callback approach to listening, to no avail.

I took the network initalization procedures and config files straight from ST's LwIP example application.

This is my stm32f7xx_hal_conf.h, I have a feeling there might be some misconfiguration here, because if I mess with some of these values, sending over the sockets stops working too.

```
    /**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file    BSP/inc/stm32f7xx_hal_conf.h
  * @author  MCD Application Team
  * @brief   HAL configuration file. 
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; COPYRIGHT(c) 2016 STMicroelectronics</center></h2>
  *
  * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
  * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
  *   1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  *   2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  *      and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  *   3. Neither the name of STMicroelectronics nor the names of its contributors
  *      may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
  *      without specific prior written permission.
  *
  * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
  * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
  * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
  * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
  * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
  * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
  * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
  * CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
  * OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
  * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */ 

/* Define to prevent recursive inclusion -------------------------------------*/
#ifndef __STM32F7xx_HAL_CONF_H
#define __STM32F7xx_HAL_CONF_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
#endif

/* Exported types ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported constants --------------------------------------------------------*/

/* ########################## Module Selection ############################## */
/**
  * @brief This is the list of modules to be used in the HAL driver 
  */
#define HAL_MODULE_ENABLED  
#define HAL_ADC_MODULE_ENABLED    
/* #define HAL_CAN_MODULE_ENABLED    */
/* #define HAL_CAN_LEGACY_MODULE_ENABLED    */  
 #define HAL_CRC_MODULE_ENABLED    
/* #define HAL_CRYP_MODULE_ENABLED   */ 
/* #define HAL_DAC_MODULE_ENABLED    */  
#define HAL_DCMI_MODULE_ENABLED 
#define HAL_DMA_MODULE_ENABLED
#define HAL_DMA2D_MODULE_ENABLED 
 #define HAL_ETH_MODULE_ENABLED    
#define HAL_FLASH_MODULE_ENABLED 
/* #define HAL_NAND_MODULE_ENABLED   */
#define HAL_NOR_MODULE_ENABLED
/* #define HAL_PCCARD_MODULE_ENABLED */
#define HAL_SRAM_MODULE_ENABLED
#define HAL_SDRAM_MODULE_ENABLED
/* #define HAL_HASH_MODULE_ENABLED   */ 
#define HAL_GPIO_MODULE_ENABLED
#define HAL_I2C_MODULE_ENABLED
#define HAL_I2S_MODULE_ENABLED
/* #define HAL_IWDG_MODULE_ENABLED   */ 
#define HAL_LTDC_MODULE_ENABLED 
#define HAL_PWR_MODULE_ENABLED   
#define HAL_QSPI_MODULE_ENABLED   
#define HAL_RCC_MODULE_ENABLED 
/* #define HAL_RNG_MODULE_ENABLED    */  
#define HAL_RTC_MODULE_ENABLED
#define HAL_SAI_MODULE_ENABLED
#define HAL_SD_MODULE_ENABLED
/* #define HAL_SPDIFRX_MODULE_ENABLED */
/* #define HAL_SPI_MODULE_ENABLED    */
#define HAL_TIM_MODULE_ENABLED
#define HAL_UART_MODULE_ENABLED 
/* #define HAL_USART_MODULE_ENABLED  */ 
/* #define HAL_IRDA_MODULE_ENABLED   */ 
/* #define HAL_SMARTCARD_MODULE_ENABLED */
/* #define HAL_WWDG_MODULE_ENABLED   */ 
#define HAL_CORTEX_MODULE_ENABLED
/* #define HAL_PCD_MODULE_ENABLED    */
/* #define HAL_HCD_MODULE_ENABLED    */


/* ########################## HSE/HSI Values adaptation ##################### */
/**
  * @brief Adjust the value of External High Speed oscillator (HSE) used in your application.
  *        This value is used by the RCC HAL module to compute the system frequency
  *        (when HSE is used as system clock source, directly or through the PLL).  
  */
#if !defined  (HSE_VALUE) 
  #define HSE_VALUE    ((uint32_t)25000000U) /*!< Value of the External oscillator in Hz */
#endif /* HSE_VALUE */

#if !defined  (HSE_STARTUP_TIMEOUT)
  #define HSE_STARTUP_TIMEOUT    ((uint32_t)100U)   /*!< Time out for HSE start up, in ms */
#endif /* HSE_STARTUP_TIMEOUT */

/**
  * @brief Internal High Speed oscillator (HSI) value.
  *        This value is used by the RCC HAL module to compute the system frequency
  *        (when HSI is used as system clock source, directly or through the PLL). 
  */
#if !defined  (HSI_VALUE)
  #define HSI_VALUE    ((uint32_t)16000000U) /*!< Value of the Internal oscillator in Hz*/
#endif /* HSI_VALUE */

/**
  * @brief Internal Low Speed oscillator (LSI) value.
  */
#if !defined  (LSI_VALUE) 
 #define LSI_VALUE  ((uint32_t)32000U)       /*!< LSI Typical Value in Hz*/    
#endif /* LSI_VALUE */                      /*!< Value of the Internal Low Speed oscillator in Hz
                                             The real value may vary depending on the variations
                                             in voltage and temperature.  */
/**
  * @brief External Low Speed oscillator (LSE) value.
  */
#if !defined  (LSE_VALUE)
 #define LSE_VALUE  ((uint32_t)32768U)    /*!< Value of the External Low Speed oscillator in Hz */
#endif /* LSE_VALUE */

#if !defined  (LSE_STARTUP_TIMEOUT)
  #define LSE_STARTUP_TIMEOUT    ((uint32_t)5000U)   /*!< Time out for LSE start up, in ms */
#endif /* LSE_STARTUP_TIMEOUT */

/**
  * @brief External clock source for I2S peripheral
  *        This value is used by the I2S HAL module to compute the I2S clock source 
  *        frequency, this source is inserted directly through I2S_CKIN pad. 
  */
#if !defined  (EXTERNAL_CLOCK_VALUE)
  #define EXTERNAL_CLOCK_VALUE    ((uint32_t)12288000U) /*!< Value of the Internal oscillator in Hz*/
#endif /* EXTERNAL_CLOCK_VALUE */

/* Tip: To avoid modifying this file each time you need to use different HSE,
   ===  you can define the HSE value in your toolchain compiler preprocessor. */

/* ########################### System Configuration ######################### */
/**
  * @brief This is the HAL system configuration section
  */     
#define  VDD_VALUE                    ((uint32_t)3300U) /*!< Value of VDD in mv */
#define  TICK_INT_PRIORITY            ((uint32_t)0x15U) /*!< tick interrupt priority */
#define  USE_RTOS                     0U
#define  PREFETCH_ENABLE              1U
#define  ART_ACCLERATOR_ENABLE        1U /* To enable instruction cache and prefetch */

/* ########################## Assert Selection ############################## */
/**
  * @brief Uncomment the line below to expanse the "assert_param" macro in the 
  *        HAL drivers code
  */
/* #define USE_FULL_ASSERT    1 */

/* ################## Ethernet peripheral configuration ##################### */

/* Section 1 : Ethernet peripheral configuration */

/* MAC ADDRESS: MAC_ADDR0:MAC_ADDR1:MAC_ADDR2:MAC_ADDR3:MAC_ADDR4:MAC_ADDR5 */
#define MAC_ADDR0   0x84
#define MAC_ADDR1   0x16
#define MAC_ADDR2   0x43
#define MAC_ADDR3   0xA6
#define MAC_ADDR4   0x3B
#define MAC_ADDR5   0x2A

 /* Definition of the Ethernet driver buffers size and count */
 #define ETH_RX_BUF_SIZE                ETH_MAX_PACKET_SIZE /* buffer size for receive               */
 #define ETH_TX_BUF_SIZE                ETH_MAX_PACKET_SIZE /* buffer size for transmit              */
 #define ETH_RXBUFNB                    ((uint32_t)4U)       /* 4 Rx buffers of size ETH_RX_BUF_SIZE  */
 #define ETH_TXBUFNB                    ((uint32_t)4U)       /* 4 Tx buffers of size ETH_TX_BUF_SIZE  */

/* Section 2: PHY configuration section */
 /* DP83848_PHY_ADDRESS Address*/
 #define DP83848_PHY_ADDRESS           0
 /* PHY Reset delay these values are based on a 1 ms Systick interrupt*/
 #define PHY_RESET_DELAY                 ((uint32_t)0x000000FFU)
 /* PHY Configuration delay */
 #define PHY_CONFIG_DELAY                ((uint32_t)0x00000FFFU)

 #define PHY_READ_TO                     ((uint32_t)0x0000FFFFU)
 #define PHY_WRITE_TO                    ((uint32_t)0x0000FFFFU)


 /* Section 3: Common PHY Registers */

 #define PHY_BCR                         ((uint16_t)0x00U)    /*!< Transceiver Basic Control Register   */
 #define PHY_BSR                         ((uint16_t)0x01U)    /*!< Transceiver Basic Status Register    */

 #define PHY_RESET                       ((uint16_t)0x8000U)  /*!< PHY Reset */
 #define PHY_LOOPBACK                    ((uint16_t)0x4000U)  /*!< Select loop-back mode */
 #define PHY_FULLDUPLEX_100M             ((uint16_t)0x2100U)  /*!< Set the full-duplex mode at 100 Mb/s */
 #define PHY_HALFDUPLEX_100M             ((uint16_t)0x2000U)  /*!< Set the half-duplex mode at 100 Mb/s */
 #define PHY_FULLDUPLEX_10M              ((uint16_t)0x0100U)  /*!< Set the full-duplex mode at 10 Mb/s  */
 #define PHY_HALFDUPLEX_10M              ((uint16_t)0x0000U)  /*!< Set the half-duplex mode at 10 Mb/s  */
 #define PHY_AUTONEGOTIATION             ((uint16_t)0x1000U)  /*!< Enable auto-negotiation function     */
 #define PHY_RESTART_AUTONEGOTIATION     ((uint16_t)0x0200U)  /*!< Restart auto-negotiation function    */
 #define PHY_POWERDOWN                   ((uint16_t)0x0800U)  /*!< Select the power down mode           */
 #define PHY_ISOLATE                     ((uint16_t)0x0400U)  /*!< Isolate PHY from MII                 */

 #define PHY_AUTONEGO_COMPLETE           ((uint16_t)0x0020U)  /*!< Auto-Negotiation process completed   */
 #define PHY_LINKED_STATUS               ((uint16_t)0x0004U)  /*!< Valid link established               */
 #define PHY_JABBER_DETECTION            ((uint16_t)0x0002U)  /*!< Jabber condition detected            */

 /* Section 4: Extended PHY Registers */
 #define PHY_SR                          ((uint16_t)0x10U)    /*!< PHY status register Offset                      */
 #define PHY_MICR                        ((uint16_t)0x11U)    /*!< MII Interrupt Control Register                  */
 #define PHY_MISR                        ((uint16_t)0x12U)    /*!< MII Interrupt Status and Misc. Control Register */

 #define PHY_LINK_STATUS                 ((uint16_t)0x0001U)  /*!< PHY Link mask                                   */
 #define PHY_SPEED_STATUS                ((uint16_t)0x0002U)  /*!< PHY Speed mask                                  */
 #define PHY_DUPLEX_STATUS               ((uint16_t)0x0004U)  /*!< PHY Duplex mask                                 */

 #define PHY_MICR_INT_EN                 ((uint16_t)0x0002U)  /*!< PHY Enable interrupts                           */
 #define PHY_MICR_INT_OE                 ((uint16_t)0x0001U)  /*!< PHY Enable output interrupt events              */

 #define PHY_MISR_LINK_INT_EN            ((uint16_t)0x0020U)  /*!< Enable Interrupt on change of link status       */
 #define PHY_LINK_INTERRUPT              ((uint16_t)0x2000U)  /*!< PHY link status interrupt mask                  */

/* ################## SPI peripheral configuration ########################## */

/* CRC FEATURE: Use to activate CRC feature inside HAL SPI Driver
* Activated: CRC code is present inside driver
* Deactivated: CRC code cleaned from driver
*/

#define USE_SPI_CRC                     0U

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
  * @brief Include module's header file 
  */

#ifdef HAL_RCC_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_rcc.h"
#endif /* HAL_RCC_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_GPIO_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_gpio.h"
#endif /* HAL_GPIO_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_DMA_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_dma.h"
#endif /* HAL_DMA_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_CORTEX_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_cortex.h"
#endif /* HAL_CORTEX_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_ADC_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_adc.h"
#endif /* HAL_ADC_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_CAN_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_can.h"
#endif /* HAL_CAN_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_CAN_LEGACY_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_can_legacy.h"
#endif /* HAL_CAN_LEGACY_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_CEC_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_cec.h"
#endif /* HAL_CEC_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_CRC_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_crc.h"
#endif /* HAL_CRC_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_CRYP_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_cryp.h" 
#endif /* HAL_CRYP_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_DMA2D_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_dma2d.h"
#endif /* HAL_DMA2D_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_DAC_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_dac.h"
#endif /* HAL_DAC_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_DCMI_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_dcmi.h"
#endif /* HAL_DCMI_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_ETH_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_eth.h"
#endif /* HAL_ETH_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_FLASH_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_flash.h"
#endif /* HAL_FLASH_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_SRAM_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_sram.h"
#endif /* HAL_SRAM_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_NOR_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_nor.h"
#endif /* HAL_NOR_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_NAND_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_nand.h"
#endif /* HAL_NAND_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_SDRAM_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f7xx_hal_sdram.h"
#endif /* HAL_SDRAM_MODULE_ENABLED */      

#ifdef HAL_HASH_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_hash.h"
#endif /* HAL_HASH_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_I2C_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_i2c.h"
#endif /* HAL_I2C_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_I2S_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_i2s.h"
#endif /* HAL_I2S_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_IWDG_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_iwdg.h"
#endif /* HAL_IWDG_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_LPTIM_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_lptim.h"
#endif /* HAL_LPTIM_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_LTDC_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_ltdc.h"
#endif /* HAL_LTDC_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_PWR_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_pwr.h"
#endif /* HAL_PWR_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_QSPI_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_qspi.h"
#endif /* HAL_QSPI_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_RNG_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_rng.h"
#endif /* HAL_RNG_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_RTC_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_rtc.h"
#endif /* HAL_RTC_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_SAI_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_sai.h"
#endif /* HAL_SAI_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_SD_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_sd.h"
#endif /* HAL_SD_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_SPDIFRX_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_spdifrx.h"
#endif /* HAL_SPDIFRX_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_SPI_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_spi.h"
#endif /* HAL_SPI_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_TIM_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_tim.h"
#endif /* HAL_TIM_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_UART_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_uart.h"
#endif /* HAL_UART_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_USART_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_usart.h"
#endif /* HAL_USART_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_IRDA_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_irda.h"
#endif /* HAL_IRDA_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_SMARTCARD_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_smartcard.h"
#endif /* HAL_SMARTCARD_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_WWDG_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_wwdg.h"
#endif /* HAL_WWDG_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_PCD_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_pcd.h"
#endif /* HAL_PCD_MODULE_ENABLED */

#ifdef HAL_HCD_MODULE_ENABLED
 #include "stm32f7xx_hal_hcd.h"
#endif /* HAL_HCD_MODULE_ENABLED */

/* Exported macro ------------------------------------------------------------*/
#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  The assert_param macro is used for function's parameters check.
  * @param  expr: If expr is false, it calls assert_failed function
  *         which reports the name of the source file and the source
  *         line number of the call that failed. 
  *         If expr is true, it returns no value.
  * @retval None
  */
  #define assert_param(expr) ((expr) ? (void)0 : assert_failed((uint8_t *)__FILE__, __LINE__))
/* Exported functions ------------------------------------------------------- */
  void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line);
#else
  #define assert_param(expr) ((void)0U)
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* __STM32F7xx_HAL_CONF_H */


/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

I would really appreciate your help, I've been stuck on this for days!

Comment: it is hard to say anything or figure it out your problem from your stm32f7xx_hal_conf.h file. Is receiving IP address configured correctly? You should set dinamic IP address to your device to communicate your board if you don't have dhcp server. If you don't set, you can sent data to device but you can not receive any data from device.